# How to create new list with column data from 2 dimensinal list

Tags: python, list

I have this list

```
[[['21832', '1524', '30', '133'], ['16142', '1233', '17', '113']], 
 [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1277', '18', '118']], 
 [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1278', '18', '118']], 
 [['25919', '1658', '35', '141'], ['19081', '1344', '21', '124']]]
```

And I want to create new list like,

```
[21832,23296,23296,25919]
[1524,1570,1570,1658]
[30,34,34,35]
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, you can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

lst = [[['21832', '1524', '30', '133'], ['16142', '1233', '17', '113']], 
       [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1277', '18', '118']], 
       [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1278', '18', '118']], 
       [['25919', '1658', '35', '141'], ['19081', '1344', '21', '124']]]

res = np.array(lst)[:,0,:3].T
```

Result:

```
array([['21832', '23296', '23296', '25919'],
       ['1524', '1570', '1570', '1658'],
       ['30', '34', '34', '35']],
      dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` with unpacking:

```
d = [[['21832', '1524', '30', '133'], ['16142', '1233', '17', '113']], 
 [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1277', '18', '118']], 
 [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1278', '18', '118']], 
 [['25919', '1658', '35', '141'], ['19081', '1344', '21', '124']]]
new_d = list(map(list, zip(*[list(map(int, a)) for [*a, b], _ in d])))
```

Output:

```
[[21832, 23296, 23296, 25919], [1524, 1570, 1570, 1658], [30, 34, 34, 35]]
```

Comment: Is this method faster than other indexing methods?

Comment: @10donovanr This answer is fairly efficient as it is using `map` with pre-defined functions, `list` and `int`. I greated a gist here with full timings for these answers: https://gist.github.com/Ajax12345/def08ffd9325248e041e1fdd43178ce9

Answer (score 0):

All great answers! I have to throw in a list comprehension solution...

```
test_lists = [[['21832', '1524', '30', '133'], ['16142', '1233', '17', '113']], 
 [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1277', '18', '118']], 
 [['23296', '1570', '34', '138'], ['17243', '1278', '18', '118']], 
 [['25919', '1658', '35', '141'], ['19081', '1344', '21', '124']]]

first_lists = [first_list[0] for first_list in test_lists]    

firsts_list = [elements[0] for elements in first_lists]
seconds_list = [elements[1] for elements in first_lists]
thirds_list = [elements[2] for elements in first_lists]
fourths_list = [elements[3] for elements in first_lists]

# firsts_list: ['21832', '23296', '23296', '25919']
# seconds_list: ['1524', '1570', '1570', '1658']
# thirds_list: ['30', '34', '34', '35']
# fourths_list: ['133', '138', '138', '141']
```